# How to implement FrameLayout Functionality in android

Tags: android, android-framelayout

Hi i am new for android and in my app i am working on FrameLayout

My problem is i want to design my screen like my below image 1

but according to my code i am getting like my below image 2 please help me how can do this

### code:-

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginLeft="30dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="30dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="250dp"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:weightSum="3">

        <FrameLayout
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="match_parent">

            <FrameLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:layout_centerInParent="true"
                android:background="@color/splash"
                android:padding="5dp">

                <ImageView
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:src="@drawable/ic_launcher" />

            </FrameLayout>

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="35dp"
                android:layout_height="35dp"
                android:layout_gravity="top|right"
                android:layout_marginRight="-20dp"
                android:layout_marginTop="-10dp"
                android:background="@android:color/holo_orange_dark"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:text="1"
                android:textColor="@android:color/white" />

        </FrameLayout>

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_weight="1" />

        <FrameLayout
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_marginLeft="30dp">

            <FrameLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:layout_centerInParent="true"
                android:background="@color/splash"
                android:padding="5dp">

                <ImageView
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:src="@drawable/ic_launcher" />
            </FrameLayout>

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="35dp"
                android:layout_height="35dp"
                android:layout_gravity="top|right"
                android:layout_marginRight="-20dp"
                android:layout_marginTop="-10dp"
                android:background="@android:color/holo_orange_dark"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:text="2"
                android:textColor="@android:color/white" />

        </FrameLayout>

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_weight="1" />

        <FrameLayout
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_marginLeft="30dp">

            <FrameLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:layout_centerInParent="true"
                android:background="@color/splash"
                android:padding="5dp">

                <ImageView
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:src="@drawable/ic_launcher" />

            </FrameLayout>

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="35dp"
                android:layout_height="35dp"
                android:layout_gravity="top|right"
                android:layout_marginRight="-20dp"
                android:layout_marginTop="-10dp"
                android:background="@android:color/holo_orange_dark"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:text="3"
                android:textColor="@android:color/white" />

        </FrameLayout>

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_weight="1" />

        <FrameLayout
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_marginLeft="30dp">

            <FrameLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:layout_centerInParent="true"
                android:background="@color/splash"
                android:padding="5dp">

                <ImageView
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:src="@drawable/ic_launcher" />

            </FrameLayout>

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="35dp"
                android:layout_height="35dp"
                android:layout_gravity="top|right"
                android:layout_marginRight="-20dp"
                android:layout_marginTop="-10dp"
                android:background="@android:color/holo_orange_dark"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:text="4"
                android:textColor="@android:color/white" />

        </FrameLayout>

    </LinearLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

### image1:-

[image]

### image2:-

[image]

Answer (score 0):

So not going to lie, I hated it when I started working with XML in Android. It is like putting a puzzle together without even knowing what the pieces of the puzzle are. Anyway, you start to get the hang of it and can come up with some interesting ideas. There are a lot of ways to handle your views, something like this should work.

Make a layout called something like `view_notification_icon.xml` that looks like:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="wrap-content"
    android:layout_height="wrap-content"
    android:layout_margin="10dp" >

    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_margin="18dp"
        android:src="@drawable/ic_launcher" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/tv_count"
        android:layout_width="35dp"
        android:layout_height="35dp"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:background="@android:color/holo_orange_dark"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:text="3"
        android:textColor="@android:color/white" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

*If the image source needs scaling you can use min/max height, scaleType, and adjustViewBounds attributes on the ImageView as needed*

Then you can provide the main container layout like so

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="horizontal">

    <include layout="@layout/view_notification_icon" id="@+id/icon_1" />

    <include layout="@layout/view_notification_icon" id="@+id/icon_2" />

    <include layout="@layout/view_notification_icon" id="@+id/icon_3" />

    <include layout="@layout/view_notification_icon" id="@+id/icon_4" />
</LinearLayout>
```

Then in java you can access/modify the icon text like so

```
private void modifyNotificationValue(int containerID, int count){
    View container = findViewById(containerID);
    ((TextView) container.findViewById(R.id.tv_count)).setText(String.valueOf(count));
}
```

**NOTE**

Obviously this can be made more efficient (getting the views in onCreate so you aren't overusing findViewById for example); also I haven't tested this so it may need some tweaking, but it should help get you started.

Comment: hi zgc 7009 ur there?